# Excluding null entries from multiples values with SQL

Tags: sql, null, multiple-tables

From 3 different tables, I want to know if a person (table1), with multiple visit in a store (table2), have purchased toys and enjoyed them (table3). In table3, 0 stand as either negative (so not enjoyed) or not bought. 1 stands for positive. Every visit has its own identification number.

My problem is that for every ID in table1, I have multiple entries for table2 for which I have multiple entries for table3 and only one of them is null.

```
Person      Visit                 Toy 
ID   age    Number Visit  ID      number name   value
1    12     1        1     1      1      Plane  
2    10     2        1     2      1      Train  1
            3        2     1      2      Plane  1
            4        2     2      2      Train  0
                                  3      Plane  0
                                  3      Train  1
           (goes on for every id)  (goes on for every visit)
```

I want to if know how many people have enjoyed a certain toy. However, since I have some null info, I have some trouble having those for which I only have value for both of their visit. For instance, the following code works only if the null condition is placed only on one of the visits

```
Select p.id, max(toy.value) as value
from person p
join visit v on p.id = v.id
join toy t on v.number = t.number
where
((t.name='plane' and v.visit=1) 
 or (t.name='plane' and v.visit=2)) 
 and (
    (v.visit=1 and ((t.value=1 or t.value=0) is not null))
    ---and (v.visit=2 and ((t.value=1 or t.value=0) is not null))
    )
group by p.id
order by p.id
```

I have tried many ways of writing this. It does work if I try with both of null condition independently, but if I remove the `--` and try for the condition on both the visit 1 and 2, it doesn't work. Note that I am using max on the value because I want a positive value is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how many people have enjoyed a certain toy, Then you may simply write this:

```
select count(*) from toy t where t.name='TOY NAME' and t.level=1;
```

If you want something else. Then kindly clarify.

Edited Query,

```
Select p.id, max(toy.value) as value
from person p
join visit v on p.id = v.id
join toy t on v.number = t.number
where 
t.name='plane' 
and t.value is not null 
group by p.id 
order by p.id
```

Comment: In my table, I have more then just 2 visit, so this is why I have specified 2 of them. Also, do not want only those with 1, but all of them. The max is there to show the highest of the two. I'm an looking for those with an entry for both visit. With t.value=1 (or 0), you do not scan for null entries

Comment: can you clarify the meaning of column **number** and **visit** in **visit** table.

Comment: simply the Id of the visit and the nth visit for a visitor

Comment: added edited query in the answer. try it and let me know if needed any more clarification.

Comment: Again, this does not exclude the null value

Answer (score 0):

I used count as a way to eliminate all the null entries. The sum of null and a value is always null, so by adding restriction `count=2` it eliminate the null